# Conditional Matrix or Combinations in R

Tags: r, matrix, conditional-statements, combinations

I have 7 vectors :

```
vector1 = c(9,8,7,6,5)
vector2 = c(10,20,30)
vector3=c(19,27,34,40,45)
vector4=c(29,37,44)
vector5=c(39,47)
vector6=c(28,36)
vector7=c(13,42)
vector=c(vector1,vector2,vector3,vector4,vector5,vector6,vector7)

co = expand.grid(vector,vector,vector,vector,vector,vector)
```

I need a 6-variable combination table of the above vectors, but the value in each vector should not be repeated more than 2 times in each row of this table and the same numbers should not be present in each row. For example:

V1 V1 V2 V3 V4 V7

V1 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7

How can I do that?

```
V1 = c (9,8,7,6,5)
V2 = c (10,20,30)
V3 = c (19,27,34,40,45)
V4 = c (29,37,44)
V5 = c (39.47)
V6 = c (28.36)
V7 = c (13,25,42)
```

I have 7 vector groups. I want to list them in combinations with 6 variables. There should not be more than 2 members from each row of these 7 groups.

As a second condition,

```
x1 = 1: 9
x2 = 10:19
x3 = 20:29
x4 = 30: 39
x5 = 40:49
```

I have groups as seen above. There should not be more than 3 members in the x1, x2, x3, x4 or x5 group range in each row in the combination list.

For example: In a combination of 2 3 5 7 19 25, the number of x1 members should not be in the combination list because they are more than 3.

Comment: Do you need every combination that matches those requirements? Or just a way to sample from them? (And order doesn't matter, right?)

Comment: Try `combn(paste0("V", c(1:7, 1:7)), m = 6)`. Or maybe `unique(lapply(combn(paste0("V", c(1:7, 1:7)), m = 6, simplify = FALSE), sort))`

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by *"and the same numbers should not be present in each row"*, but my above comment seems like what you want?

Comment: Thanks Gregor. It works but I have more questions to solve.

Comment: Gregor, I need all the combinations. Samples won't be enough for me.


Vs have number values. For example:

V1 = c (9,8,7,6,5)
V2 = c (10,20,30)
V3 = c (19,27,34,40,45)
V4 = c (29,37,44)
V5 = c (39.47)
V6 = c (28.36)
V7 = c (13,25,44)

The result is that only the vectors are sorted. For example :
[1] "V2" "V2" "V4" "V5" "V5" "V7"
[[291]]
[1] "V2" "V2" "V4" "V5" "V7" "V7"
[[292]]
[1] "V2" "V4" "V4" "V5" "V5" "V7"

I want to print the values of numbers into them. Besides, I don't want it to be more than 1: 9, 10:19, 20:29, 30:39, 40:49 on each line. For example :

Comment: "V1" "V1" "V3" "V4" "V6" V7 "
in the form of a line. If the number values are sorted as follows,

5 6 27 29 28 25

In this case, because there are 4 numbers in the 20:29 range, I want the code to remove lines like this from the combination.

Comment: @Tim , could you edit your question with a smaller example and include the desired output along with what you have tried. As it stands, together with your comments, it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Hi @Gregor, thank you for the warning. I just started using this site. I was just following it in advance. Do you have a solution for my problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea. It's not a great answer because I didn't fully test it, but I think it should work. It's rather inefficient, and I didn't have the patience to let it run long enough to complete.

```
y = rep(vector, 2)
result = unique(
  lapply(
    Filter(f = function(x) !anyDuplicated(x),
     combn(y, m = 6, simplify = FALSE)
    ),
  sort)
)
```

Explanation: make two copies of all your inputs in a vector. Generate all combinations choosing 6 elements. Filter out any results with duplicates. Sort them so they are in a consistent order. Keep the unique combinations.

This is inefficient because the first step will generate `choose(length(y), 6) ~= 7M` combinations, which we then have to whittle down to (I think) 166,638 final combinations. But it's the simplest way I can think of to code your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your attention @Gregor but that's not what I want. This code prevents repeated combinations, but does not provide the two conditions I mentioned above.
I want vector1,2,3,4,5,6,7 members not to repeat more than 2 times in the same row and 1: 9, 10: 19 ..... to not repeat the numbers more than 3 times.
As an example: 1. If the condition is v1 = c (14,15,17,19) I want to have at most 2 of these numbers on each line.
As an example: I don't want to have 11,13,15,17 on the same line as the 2nd condition.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I missed your edit and only met the first condition. I'll leave the partial answer as a starting place for anyone who wants to work more on it.

Comment: Thank you @Gregor

Comment: Also, I'm confused that `44` is in both V4 and V7. How does that work? Is it okay for 44 to repeat because of that? My answer certainly doesn't take that into account.

Comment: In fact, 44 of the two vectors is not a problem. Of course, the number 44 must not be 2 on the same row.
I wrote the data set as an example. I can change 44. In fact, 44 was not supposed to be on 2 vector.
However, 3 numbers with v4 and v7 should not have more than 2 members on the same row.